# Convert Dates to number of Days using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the number of days corresponding to the date for each country. I have a dataset like so:

```
Date         Country  
01/03/2020    USA
02/03/2020    USA
03/03/2020    USA
07/04/2020    UK
08/04/2020    UK 
09/04/2020    UK
```

And I want to get the day numbers based on their first date the country is mentioned. So something like this:

```
Date         Country    Day_Number
01/03/2020    USA         1
02/03/2020    USA         2
03/03/2020    USA         3
07/04/2020    UK          1
08/04/2020    UK          2
09/04/2020    UK          3
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following piece of code, it will maintain a cumulative count after `groupby` operations.

```py
df['Day_Number'] = df.groupby('Country').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: That's worked, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, better close like answer, because dupe.

Comment: Only better is 1000times repeated dupes not answering...

Comment: I do it, because I think OP need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete copy-paste solution but:

You can get the number of days since January 1 1970 this way:

```py
import datetime
days = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days
# Or
days = (datetime.datetime(year, month, day) - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days
```

So you can convert your dates to numbers (days since Jan 1 1970) and then:

- keep track of the minimum per country
- subtract the corresponding minimum from each entry

Hope this helps